# Breakpoints are deleted in Eclipse CDT and MinGW using Windows

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, debugging

In a simple `Hello World Project` in Eclipse CDT (version: Kepler) on Windows 7, I tried to set breakpoints to debug the program.

However, when the program is launched, the debugger stops at the first line of `main()`, and when the `Resume` button is pressed, all the breakpoints are skipped and the program terminates with: `expect signal SIGINT when the program is resumed`.

A strange thing happened too: the same installation on a second computer in which the username  does not include spaces works fine.

The console for `gdb traces` does not report anything strange. The breakpoints are set and the execution does not report other errors (but I don't assure this is the problem).

The same settings are used on MacOS X too, but here it works fine.

Any hints? Thank you.